# JWT code examples

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

Couldn't find much on this, Documentation is not clear enough, what I'm looking for is to be able to encode and decode a JWT token in a simple manner.

https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt

Looking for something similar to Json web tokens. [API authentication using json web tokens jwt-simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956773/api-authentication-using-json-web-tokens-jwt-simple?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
int data = 123456;

// Encode

string AuthToken = JWT.Encode(data);

// Decode

int data = JWT.Decode(AuthToken)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18677837/213550

Comment: thanks for the link but i'm still at the same point, for some reason docs are not helping me, I'd appreciate if you can help me with the code.

Comment: at least on how to create one